# Getting number and off setting numbers from array in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, data-cleaning

I have array of numbers in a single column like this:

[image]

I want only that numbers for which corresponding negative numbers exist. If number exist 2 times, but negative number exist only one time, then I wanted to retain one positive and one negative number. Similarly, if number exists 3 times, and negative number appears only two times, then I want 2 set of numbers including positive and negative. In this case, I wanted to get output:

5 2 -2 -5

Orders of numbers are not relevant for me. Please do not use VBA. You can create multiple column and apply filter at the end.

---

Thank you for the response, but I wanted to get the data in column next to the values. Like:

```
5
2
-2
-5
```

Please help.

Comment: @Neeraj regarding your recent edit, you're changing the scope to have the pairings listed beside each other rather than listed?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `vlookup` formula to identify the rows, and you can use the `Filter` & `Unique` formula to get the list, or a pivot table.

First, immediately next to your data use the formula:

`=vlookup(A1*-1,$A$1:$A$1,1,0)`

**For non-365**:

This will produce an error for each instance that doesn't have a match. You can filter at this point to get your list from the existing table. You can also create a pivot table under the `Data` tab of your ribbon and inserting a pivot table. Filter the #N/A from there to get an exclusive list without hidden rows.

**For 365**:

You can use the following combination of formulas to get the exclusive list as well.

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:B8,ISNUMBER(B1:B8)),0,0)` or `=UNIQUE(FILTER($B$1:$B$8,ISNUMBER($B$1:$B$8)),0,0)` should yield the same results

As ScottCraner mentioned, you can circumvent the helper column in 365 by modifying the formula a bit more:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A8,ISNUMBER(MATCH(-A1:A8,A1:A8,0)),"")`

The `Match` here is doing something similar to the `Vlookup`, but housing that logic within the formula, so it's a cleaner solution in my opinion.

Using your data the result was { -5,-2,2,5 }

These are spill formulas so you only need to put it in one spot and it will expand the formula over the adjacent cells below where it's entered for however many cells needed to list all the unique numbers that occur. It takes into account the negatives and so on. This may be a 365 formula, so if you're on another version of excel it may not work.

Edit: Adjusted the instructions to fully address the question.

Comment: BTW: with O365 you do not need the helper: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A8,ISNUMBER(MATCH(-A1:A8,A1:A8,0)),""))`

Comment: @ScottCraner would you be alright if I modified my answer to include this? Unsure what the etiquette for this would be, but I try to avoid helpers whenever possible.

Comment: Yes,  If I comment it is because my answer does not differentiate enough to warrant it.  If you want to use my comment in the actual answer feel free.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another Office 365 solution:

1. Name the data range `DATA`
2. Put this formula anywhere: `=CONCAT(REPT(-ROW(A1:A100)&" "&ROW(A1:A100)&" ",COUNTIF(DATA,"="&ROW(A1:A100)*IF(COUNTIF(DATA,"="&-ROW(A1:A100))<COUNTIF(DATA,"="&ROW(A1:A100)),-1,1))))`

That will output the pairs into one cell.

Here's a slightly modified Step 2, which excludes duplicates: `=CONCAT(IF((COUNTIF(DATA,"="&-ROW(A1:A100))>0)*(COUNTIF(DATA,"="&ROW(A1:A100))>0),-ROW(A1:A100)&" "&ROW(A1:A100)&" ",""))`

Looks like this:

[image]

The data doesn't need to be sorted. Both methods work up to 100, but you can easily expand that by changing `A100` to `A1000` or whatever you need.

Comment: Hi @Robson You mentioned this can go up to 1000 by adjusting the code, but wouldn't this solution hit the character limit of how many character can fit into a single cell at a certain point? I like the creativity here, but curious of it's limitations

Comment: Yes - the character limit per cell is 32,767 characters, which is quite a lot, but with enough data this could be reached. I only used the single-cell output because that's how it was formatted in the original question. My preferred solution would be to use VBA and then output the result in separate cells.

Comment: That's what I figured although 32K is a pretty high amount, I'd be dizzy seeing that much in a single cell. I didn't see any mention of needing the result in a single-cell, only a single column,  unless it was edited out of the scope.

Comment: Me too. I always prefer to have one piece of data per cell. Unfortunately the original question didn't have any of the stuff after the line, so the output was just described as "5 2 -2 -5"

Comment: Understandable then, I'm right there with you as 1 per cell, with the exception of when creating unique keys to pull other data from.